# Adding date picker to Access 2010 report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, reporting

I have an Access 2010 report which currently displays all the records from a table. I want to add a date picker, which enables users to select a date on the report and display all records later than the selected date.

Is this possible in Access 2010 reports? If so how?

Comment: You're going to need to prompt the user for the date parameters. There's a couple ways this could be done. In a form, in the `WHERE` clause in `VBA`, or in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to do this:

1) Set a where clause in the SQL code for the report and have it be:

```
WHERE SomeColumnDate = EnterDate
```

from there when the user opens the report it will prompt them for the date.

2) This one is cleaner however more complicated, you need to create a form with a text box    which is formatted to be a dateTime and then a button.  In the report Set a WHERE clause again like this:

```
WHERE SomeColumnDate = Stuff
```

in the design view for the query go to the WHERE statement and change the condition to [FORMS]![FORMNAME]![TEXTBOXNAME] From there you will then need to go into VBA code for a button in the form and set it to do this code when clicked:

```
Dim strWhereClause As String
strWhereClause = "SomeColumnDate = " + Me.txtDate.Text
DoCmd.OpenReport "SOMEREPORTNAME",acReportView,,strWhereClase
```

this will make it once you click that button it will run the report with the date selected by the user.